# Oracle datatype for storing very small numbers

Tags: oracle

What data type should I use if I want to store very small number (e.g. 0.0000034)

If I use Number(10,9) data type, with input 0.000001, will it be stored as 0.000001000 or just 0.000001?

Answer (score 1):

The NUMBER type in Oracle is a variable precision, base 10 floating point value which only stores the actual digits needed to represent a number, which in this case would be a digit containing `1` and an exponent of -6. From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209):

> Internal Numeric Format
>
> Oracle Database stores numeric data in variable-length format. Each value is stored in scientific notation, with 1 byte used to store the exponent and up to 20 bytes to store the mantissa. The resulting value is limited to 38 digits of precision. Oracle Database does not store leading and trailing zeros. For example, the number 412 is stored in a format similar to 4.12 x 102, with 1 byte used to store the exponent(2) and 2 bytes used to store the three significant digits of the mantissa(4,1,2). Negative numbers include the sign in their length.
>
> Taking this into account, the column size in bytes for a particular numeric data value NUMBER(p), where p is the precision of a given value, can be calculated using the following formula:
>
> ROUND((length(p)+s)/2))+1
>
> where s equals zero if the number is positive, and s equals 1 if the number is negative.
>
> Zero and positive and negative infinity (only generated on import from Oracle Database, Version 5) are stored using unique representations. Zero and negative infinity each require 1 byte; positive infinity requires 2 bytes.

Best of luck.

Comment: Why doesnt he use float datatype ? I just want to note i faced in an oracle version problem with 000 .. i mean 1.00100 will be posted like 1.001.. i dont rember how i solve it

Comment: He could use BINARY_FLOAT or BINARY_DOUBLE, but why? First, they're imprecise, suffering from all the disadvantages of any base 2^n floating point type.Second, in this case where OP seems to be concerned about the space requirements, for the number he's interested in `NUMBER` is more space-efficient. Third, if you need to display 1.001 as 1.00100 you could use `TO_CHAR(n, '0.00000')`. [SQLFIddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1483/2). Best of luck.